# set color in class property and use that property for binding in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to set a color in a property and use that property to bind to the background color of my window.
i.e the value set in the property will be binded to my window background.

The code below is not working for me.

**class**

```
public static class configclas
    {
        public static int UserId { get; set; }
        public static string UserName { get; set; }
        private static string _klant;
        public static String Klant
        {
            get { return _klant; }
            set { _klant = value; }
        }

    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="SmartAccount.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
        Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid x:Name="setcolor" Background="{Binding Klant}">
        <wpfTool:ColorPicker x:Name="colorPicker" Width="40" Height="30" Canvas.Left="3" Visibility="Visible" Canvas.Top="208"></wpfTool:ColorPicker>
        <Button x:Name="btnsubmit" Height="30" Width="50" Content="submit" Margin="0,90,0,0" Click="btnsubmit_Click_1"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**test.xaml.cs**

```
 private void btnsubmit_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var clrr = colorPicker.SelectedColor.ToString();

            BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
            var bgcolor = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)bc.ConvertFrom(colorPicker.SelectedColor.ToString());
            configclas.Klant = clrr;
            }


        }
```

Comment: I may be wrong but i don't think you can bind a colour to it's string value. Try setting your klant property to be a `Color` instead of `String`

Comment: @DNKROZ can you provide me a small demo if you have